# shell loop match a regex in the current line

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to create a script to fix a csv file like this:

```
field_one,field_two,field_three
,field_two,field_three
```

So I need to check inside my loop if the current line is missing field_one and replace it with sed with a new value for field_one (overwrite the line missing field_one).

For this i have a loop but i need some help with identifying if the line is missing field one or not. I should probably use grep? but how to use it in a loop and get its response?

```
while read -r line; do  
    # this is pseudocode:
    # if $line matches regex then
         #  sed 's/,/newfieldone/'
         #  overwrite the corrected line in the file
    # end if
done < my_file
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the current line is missing field_one"?

Comment: @Tichodroma: the current line being read by the loop.

Comment: @Tichodroma: i have a ~100 line file, where a few lines are missing field_one. in my loop im reading the file line by line trying to identify which one is missing field_one

Answer (score 3):

Inside your loop you can run following sed command:

```
sed 's/^\s*,/newfieldone,/'
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest of the lot. +1

Answer (score 2):

To see if a line begins with a `,` and is hence missing field one, you can use `if [[ "$line" =~ ^, ]]`.

For example:

```
while read -r line; do  
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^, ]]
  then
    echo "newfieldone$line"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < my_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the heck of it, here's a solution in awk:

```
awk '{FS=","} {if ($1 == "") print "field_one" $0;else print $0} ' < /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: You also need to set `OFS=","`

Comment: @glennjackman in this case he doesn't, print will implicitly used FS to concatenate its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/^,/fieldone,/' YOURFILE
```

Will replace every line starting `,` with `fieldone,` (inplace, so the original file gets overwritten, if you need a backup, try `-i.backup`).

If you want a dynamic `fieldone` value, well it depends, how dynamic want it to be :-), e.g.:

```
MYDYNAMICFIELDONE="DYNAF1"
sed -i "s/^,/${MYDYNAMICFIELDONE},/" YOURFILE
```

Or with your `while` loop:

```
while read -r line; do  
    MYDYNAMICFIELDONE="SET IT"
    sed -i "s/^,/${MYDYNAMICFIELDONE},/"
done < my_file > tmpfile
mv tmpfile my_file
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk '{
       /^,/ { 
               DYNAF1="SET IT HERE"
               print gensub("^,",DYNAF1 ",","g",$0)
            }
      } INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e "/^,/s/^,\([^,]*\),\([^,]\)/new_field_one,\1,\2/" < my_file
```

**Edit:** This probably is too complicated. Take one of the other fine answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
a=Field_one,Field_two,Field_three
sed '/^,/c\'$a'' file
field_one,field_two,field_three
Field_one,Field_two,Field_three
```

Or if just inserting `field_one`:

```
a=Field_one
sed '/^,/s/^/'$a'/' file
field_one,field_two,field_three
Field_one,field_two,field_three
```

Answer (score 1):

with sed try something like that:

```
sed -i 's|\(^,.*\)|new_field_one\1|g' <your file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple bash solution using `case` statemetn:

```
while read -r line; do  
  case "$line" in
    ,*) printf "%s%s\n" newfieldone "$line" ;;
    *)  printf "%s\n" "$line" ;;
  esac
done < my_file
```

`case` uses "glob" matching, not regular expressions, so `,*` matches a string beginning with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty short 1-liner with `awk`

```
awk '{$1="field_one"}1' FS=',' OFS=',' file.csv
```

Comment: Won't this update all fields instead of just the missing first field. Also, you missed a quote before `BEGIN`. Update it quickly before `jo-so` sees it. :P

Comment: @Jaypal oops. good catch.  And yes it updates all fields which is perhaps not as efficient but it did let me make it 6 chars shorter ;) Which now that I think about it, using BEGIN actually made it longer. Can't have that!

Comment: Hehe yea see I am absorbing all the good stuff from you !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

. . . and another `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '$1==""{$1="field_one"}1' FS=',' OFS=',' file
```

Comment: P.S. there is an superfluous ';' -- it must die!

Answer (score 0):

What about the use of bash only

```
while IFS=\, read field_one field_two rest_of_line
  echo "${field_one:-default_field_one_value},$field_two,$rest_of_line"
doen < my_file > my_corecct_file
```

where the 'default_field_one_value' is used if the 'field_one' is empty